# SQL query to delete all tables and their data from a specific schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to write a SQL query to delete all tables and their data from a specific schema.

For example in my database I have tables with schema `dws6` and I want a script in SQL that will delete all the tables within the schema `dws6`.

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried below script and its working perfectly

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT 'Drop Table ' + Table_Schema + '.' + Table_Name + ';'
FROM Information_Schema.Tables
WHERE Table_Type = 'BASE TABLE'
AND Table_Schema = 'dws6'

OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @SQL

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
--PRINT @SQL
EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL

FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @SQL
END
CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor;
```

Answer (score 0):

This Query will  generate all the DROP TABLE statements for you and PRINT the SQL statments

```
DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @Sql = 
        COALESCE(@Sql, '') + 'DROP TABLE [DBO1].' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) + ';' + CHAR(13)
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dws6'

    PRINT @Sql
```

Comment: Can you pls explain me the importance of COALESCE(@Sql, '') in this situation.

Comment: @balaji the string which will cross the size of varchar(8000) it will show error(binary data will be truncated)  to avoid that one we will concatenate string

Comment: Your solution absolutely works fine, my question is regarding COALESCE, I know what is the use of COALESCE. But in this situation, I am not able to understand what is the role of COALESCE()

Comment: see @balaji see if you remove  COALESCE function and passing null  means string it will not print anything so while avoiding that scenario i used
COALESCE